# Django Rest Framework admin panel not using custom User Manager

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-users, django-managers

I have implemented a CustomUser and CustomUserManager in my DRF app. The tutorials I have followed are [this one](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/) and [this one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example), which are nearly identical approaches to creating a custom user and custom user manager.

I placed a print statement in the create_user and create_superuser methods of the custom user manager to check it was being used correctly.

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    print("manager used")
    ...
```

When I use the command `python manage.py addsuperuser`, the print statement runs, great. When I use the built-in admin panel of the DRF framework localhost:8000/admin to create a new admin or regular user, the statement doesn't run, however, the user is created without error.

As far as I can see, the implementation is meant to have the admin panel use the new customer user manager, but that doesn't seem to be the case. What have I done wrong?

Comment: have you managed to solve this?